# MySql emulation running on Microsoft SQL 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have an application that cannot be altered. The only configuration changes permitted on the application are : host ip, username and password.

The application streams data into a MySql database. Another application then sends this data onto a Microsoft SQL 2008 server.

I would like to remove this middle step and wondered if anyone knew of a way that Microsoft SQL Server 2008 could be configured to 'pretend' to be a MySql database?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why 'send' the data to the SQL Server when you can just create a linked server?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. MySql and MSSQL are 2 completely different products with different connectionprotocols, a different SQL dialect, different behaviour at times and so on.

I'm sorry.